# Icelink : video, voice and text chat

Tags: android, video-conversion, websync

I want to implement video audio and text chat in native Android using [Icelink](https://help.frozenmountain.com/docs/icelink3/getting-started/introducing-icelink). I implement demo provided by Icelink but it makes a conference call. I want to make one to one call using request and answer signalling method. Till now I did with connect server and bind user with it. i use [Websync](https://docs.frozenmountain.com/websync4/) for server-side implementation.

Now the problem is what can I do for getting all the users.?? Suppose I will get all users from server side then how can I send a request from one user to other user and connect with upon second user's response??

Follow this diagram : [Signaling Diagram](https://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink2/#class=icelink-diagrams-signalling)

if anyone implemented or worked with Icelink and Websync please help me...Thanks

Comment: if anyone require code..i will provide..

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes quite late but I hope it's still useful for you.

The example provided with IceLink does indeed work as a conference call because all the users join the same *WebSync* channel and the example is setup to create a connection to a user that joins the channel.

For a simple and quick solution, you could have only two people join a single channel, then it's only a two person conference.

For something more advanced, note that IceLink is signalling agnostic. You can provide your own signalling mechanism as long as you can pass the offer and answer messages between two clients.

Comment: have you ever implement such mechanism ??
I implemented that demo provide by icelink but can't understand how to send offer to another user and get response from that user.??

Comment: Let me try and clarify this, are you asking how to send and receive messages to a single remote peer using WebSync?

Comment: exactly..i want to make mechanism like video calling.. first of all one user can call to another ..then other receive the notification that one want to (or ask to) join ..then second user give response..on their response one can join or discard ...hope you can understand..

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I put the users in the same WebSync channel and A Publishes in that channel with Ring message (as an example) and the other one, inside onReceive, gets that message and I show prompt to the user and if they accept it, I communicate the Session number to user A again and then they are put in the same conference (which is one-to-one in this case)

Comment: thanks for answering @Amir ..bit its different scenario ..i want to make it like Whatsapp ..

Comment: The idea is very simple, believe me! Just use WebSync to communicate that session number to another party and that's it!